# BrowserRouter in React is giving 'adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.' prompt while warning invalid hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, mern

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar.component";
import ExercisesList from "./components/exercises-list.component";
import EditExercise from "./components/edit-exercises.component";
import CreateExercise from "./components/create-exercise.component";
import CreateUser from "./components/create-user.component";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <br/>
      <Route path="/" exact component={ExercisesList}/>
      <Route path="/edit/:id" component={EditExercise}/>
      <Route path="/create" component={CreateExercise}/>
      <Route path="/user" component={CreateUser}/>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm following a React tutorial but the package component BrowserRouter isn't working
Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I have the error messages posted here:
[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj8hV.png)

Comment: The error is saying that `React` is null (*dunno why though*). Can you add your `package.json` file to your post, and then also validate what is *actually* installed by running `npm list react react-router-dom` from the project's root directory? The line of code `BrowserRouter index.tsx:151:1` is in `react-router-dom@6`, specifically v6.3.0, but the code in your post is using v5 component API/syntax, so there's ***at least*** a version mismatch there.